# Mysterious infinite loops in C++

Tags: c++, for-loop

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    bool flag = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4, !flag; i++)
    {
        cout << "TESTING1..\n";

        for (int j = 0; j < 4, !flag; j++)
        {
            cout << "TESTING2.. \n";
            if (j = 0) flag = true;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to implement a mechanism in which I can exit out of nested loop using a flagging technique. However, the above code rather causes an infinite loop. Is there an explanation for this?

Once flag is turned true, shouldn't all loops break out?

Comment: Did you mean to write `i < 4 && !flag`?

Comment: Don't use a comma in the for-loop condition but rather `&&`

Comment: Remember, one `=` for assignment, two for equality.

Answer (score 6):

`if (j = 0) flag = true;` will never be triggered.

Did you mean instead: `if (j == 0) flag = true;`

Single `=` is assignment; double `==` is comparison.

Comment: Rule of thumb: always put a constant first in a comparison expression, so `(0 = j)` would fail early

Comment: Or write `if (!j)`. And in any case use a compiler which warns you about this, and turn on warnings.

Answer (score 0):

Two reasons:

`if (j = 0) flag = true;` will never be true, as `j=0` is assignment that evaluates to `0` -- `false`. Therefore `flag` is always `false`.

In the statement `i < 4, !flag`, the comma operator is used. This means all subexpressions are evaluated, and the expression takes the value of the last subexpression. Therefore `i < 4, !flag == !flag`.

Since `flag == false` always, `!flag` is always `true`, thus the **infinite loop**.